# Replace a substring in a string according to a list

Tags: python, list, replace

According to tutorialspoint:

> The method replace() returns a copy of the string in which the occurrences of old have been replaced with new. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm

Therefore one can use:

```
>>> text = 'fhihihi'
>>> text.replace('hi', 'o')
'fooo'
```

With this idea, given a list `[1,2,3]`, and a string `'fhihihi'` is there a method to replace a substring `hi` with 1, 2, and 3 in order? For example, this theoretical solution would yield:

```
'f123'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [format string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) out of your initial string:

```py
>>> text = 'fhihihi'
>>> replacement = [1,2,3]
>>> text.replace('hi', '{}').format(*replacement)
'f123'
```

Comment: Nice one -  as long as we don't have something like `text = 'fhihi{hi'` which fails with `ValueError: Single '}' encountered in format string`...

Comment: I tried with `timeit` and this solution is faster than `re.sub` and my naive solution by 3x. You just need to create replacement list using `range` to scale, because you don't know if the string holds 3 `hi`s or more.

Comment: You are correct both correct, this code only works under the assumptions that the text does not contain `{` or `}` or an number of `hi` different than the length of the `replacement` list. However using `range` would assume that the input is always a sequence of integers.

Comment: Acceptable and fast answer, however my program is going to use { and }'s alot so this solution would break very fast.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
import re

counter = 0

def replacer(match):
    global counter
    counter += 1
    return str(counter)

re.sub(r'hi', replacer, text)
```

This is going to be way faster than any alternative using `str.replace`

Answer (score 0):

One solution with `re.sub`:

```
text = 'fhihihi'
lst = [1,2,3]

import re
print(re.sub(r'hi', lambda g, l=iter(lst): str(next(l)), text))
```

Prints:

```
f123
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers gave good solutions. If you want to re-invent the wheel, here is one way.

```
text = "fhihihi"
target = "hi"

l = len(target)
i = 0
c = 0
new_string_list = []
while i < len(text):
    if text[i:i + l] == target:
        new_string_list.append(str(c))
        i += l
        c += 1
        continue
    new_string_list.append(text[i])
    i += 1

print("".join(new_string_list))
```

Used a list to prevent consecutive string creation.